# Remove spaces around matplotlib image with overlaid scatter for saving in original size

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have an image on which I want to plot (overlay) some points at some specific coordinates.  I used  `zorder` and `plt.scatter`.

I want to save the resulted image in its **original size** to a `numpy array variable` in Python and not offline to file (bitmap format) because I want to further process this image with the scatter plots on top without re-reading it.

My thinking is that it will be faster to save the overlaid image into a  `numpy array variable` (in **RGB image** format - `(height,width,channels)` ) in Python,  than to use `plt.savefig` and then re-read the image again with `cv2.imread` then do the necessary subsequent processing.

Speed is an important factor in my case.

I tried to set the axis limits, `àxis.('off')`, `fig.tight_layout(pad=0)`, `bbox_inches=0/'tight' in order to get rid of any trailing space around my overlaid image,  BUT :

1. there is still a trailing grey space around my image (shown when img is
   displayed with `cv2.imshow` or `cv2.imwrite` )
2. if `plt.savefig` is used --> white space around the image appears
3. after conversion to `numpy array`of overlaid image it doesn't have
   the original size.

Code below, suggestions welcome. All the things commented represent what I tried and didn't work. I have left them there so people don't suggest those again.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('Lenna.png')

h, w ,ch = np.shape(img)

# some random coordinate points
x = [30,40, 45, 60]
y = [50,60, 65, 70]

fig = plt.figure()
 
# tried to set the axes, with these commands, didn't work
#ax = plt.axes([0,0,1,1])
#fig_axes  = fig.add_subplot(111)


plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB), zorder=0,  extent=[0,w,  h, 0], interpolation="nearest")
plt.scatter(x, y, zorder=1, facecolors='b', edgecolors='k', s=50)

# tried to limit the axes size based on the image --> didn't work
#plt.xlim(0,w)
#plt.ylim(0,h)

plt.axis('off')

# again didn't do anything
#fig.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
#fig.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)


fig.tight_layout(pad=0)
fig.canvas.draw()

# save just for verification purpose that no space around the image is shown
plt.savefig("test_Lenna_scatter.png", bbox_inches=0)

# HERE I SAVE THE PLOTTED FIG IMAGE TO NUMPY ARRAY
data_img_array = np.fromstring(fig.canvas.tostring_rgb(), dtype=np.uint8, sep='')
data_img_array = data_img_array.reshape(fig.canvas.get_width_height()[::-1] + (3,))

# HERE I DISPLAY THE NUMPY ARRAY IMAGE AFTER SCATTER
# ALSO PLOT ORIG IMG TO CHECK SIMILARITY
cv2.imwrite('Lenna_scatter.png', cv2.cvtColor(data_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
cv2.imshow('Lenna Scatter', cv2.cvtColor(data_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
cv2.imshow('orig', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**RESULTS**

Overlaid Image with Scatter plots obtained from `plt.savefig`. There appears a white space (if you click on the picture) which I don't want .
[image: overlaid image]
[image: Image reconstructed numpy array]

Image reconstructed  to `numpy array` after `plt.scatter`. saved with `cv2.imwrite`. Notice gray trailing space and different image size. Which i don't want.

Comment: "nothing worked" is not a sufficient problem description. In the code that you show you do not try to save anything as numpy array. So it's unclear what you are trying to do. Please state clearly which code you use, which result you get and in how far this differs from your expectation. Please do so by [edit]ing your question.

Comment: `data_img` is a numpy array (dtype=np.uint8) and it's the RGB image. nothing worked --> before that I specify exactly what I tried and I meant that none of those commands had any effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To produce a borderless figure in matplotlib, use [`plt.axes([0,0,1,1])`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.axes) or `fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])` which will make the axes as big as the figure.

Since you want to plot an image with square pixels, the figure itself must of course have the same aspect as the image. A reasonable way to do accomplish this is to set `figsize=(w/100.,h/100.), dpi=100` where `w` and `h` are the dimensions of the image.

When saving the file, you need to choose the same dots per inch as you chose when creating the figure. The rest should be self explanatory.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = plt.imread("https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qe6z.png")
h, w ,ch = np.shape(img)

x = [30,40, 45, 60]
y = [50,60, 65, 70]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(w/100.,h/100.), dpi=100)
ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
ax.axis('off')

ax.imshow(img, zorder=0,  extent=[0,w,  h, 0], interpolation="nearest")
ax.scatter(x, y, zorder=1, facecolors='b', edgecolors='k', s=50)

plt.savefig(__file__+".png", bbox_inches=0, dpi=100)

img_recovered = plt.imread(__file__+".png")
print img_recovered.shape
```

In the window shown on screen you may have a slight border, but the saved image has the exact same size as the input image.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Solved my issue :)